# Running web browser publications from within SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, publishing-site

I have Technical publications that is supplied on a CD and DVD.

I would like to publish the entire CD to share point for multiple use by the engineering team.

These publications are made up of PDF forms technical data etc and comes in a web browsing format which can be view able directly from the CD in a browser format.

I am new to SharePoint and would like to publish these publications.

How can i do this via maybe the media WebPart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just let the users view documents in word/pdf format etc, then dump it in a document library. Share this library with all the users (maybe create a group to have `read` permissions) you want the content to have access.

1. To create document library - go to site contents -> add an app -> Document Library.
2. To dump the documents - > just select the documents, drag it to the document library and drop it :)
3. To manage permission : Go to `site settings` -> People and Groups -> (select the group link on the left if you have to ) -> create a new group -> assign proper permissions. Then go to the list, break role inheritence and grant the group you just created read permission. You can now add new users to the group and they will be able to view the content.

Comment: Thank you. That works find for the documents. Is there a way that i can allow the browsing experience to the user, either by clicking on a link that would then present the menu of the entire DVD and then give the the browsing experience of the publication. The publication gives other information other than a manual and documents

Comment: AFAIK, You will have to build a basic content editor webpart for it, and create links like - `<a href="link of the document">document tile</a>` You can get the link by going to the document lib, and click on `...` I am not sure how you can manage using the contents file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SharePoint, you can create libraries for rich media, upload the files from the DVD to that library and use Sharepoint's built in viewers to view the media. The exact approach will vary, based on your SharePoint version, the format of the media files, the flexibility you want to achieve, etc.

Ultimately, it might be easier to copy the whole contents of the DVD into a SharePoint library (or another web server), including all the sub folders with media players and stuff, and give people a link to the start html file (Home page) of the package.